# Does Ruby on Rails really fails on huge amount of concurrent connections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was using Symfony3 with PHP7 and want to explore **Ruby** and **Ruby on Rails**. My first impression was "`wow`".

I won't asking PHP7 vs Ruby. This is not related to that. What I am asking was stated here:

> https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ruby-vs-php-python-simple-microservice-performance-comparison-per
>
> Not only it's outperforming both Ruby and Python based solution it was **only engine that passed 500 concurrent connections test without failing any request**.

Is that true? Is Ruby or Python (but in my case only Ruby on Rails) really fails on such amount of requests?

How can I do to prevent? How does GitHub doesn't fail while they are using Rails or GitLab for instance?

Are there any other way to start RoR server for better performance?

I am building an app that will be higher usages and thinking to move from symfony3/PHP to Ruby. Am I doing wrong?

I am stuck at this point. Can't go further without knowing or understanding this subject better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shopify is Rails 5, and ...

> ... has been benchmarked to process over 25,000 requests per second

https://engineering.shopify.com/116502404-five-shopify-talks-at-railsconf-2016

Comment: read all. glad to hear that there is a working example. i wonder if they use puma or something else. thanks for pointing out there.